# Move Object along a straight line

Tags: java, android, math, path, line

I am trying to move a Sprite along a straight line path. I want to move it 5 pixels on the slope, or the hypotenuse each time I go through the method until I reach the end point.

I have the slope and y-intercept of the line, I also have the current X and Y values of the sprite through getX() and getY(). The final X and Y points to stop at are variables finalX and finalY.

I have tried so many equations but I can't seem to get any of them to work. What am I missing!!?

[image: Hopefully this image makes sense for what I am trying to do!]

My latest equation was trying to use y=mx+b.

```
float X = (getY() + 5 - interceptY)/slope;
float Y = slope*(getX() + 5) + interceptY;
setPosition(X, Y);
```

Comment: Can you post your latest try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can help you with a few equations from my recent game, the code moves an object given its rotation:

```
float xDirection = FloatMath.sin((float) Math.toRadians(getRotation()))
            * currentSpeed;
float yDirection = FloatMath.cos((float) Math.toRadians(getRotation()))
            * -currentSpeed;

float newX = getX() + xDirection;
float newY = getY() + yDirection;
```

You just need to derive the angle in which you need your sprite to move and this will do for you. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! =) worked purrrfectly once I figured out the rotation properly! Used this to set the rotation of my sprite, which plugged right into your code! `setRotation((float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(finalY - getY(), finalX - getX())) + 90);` By chance do you use AndEngine? =)

Comment: @Gatekeeper, You're welcome, glad I could help! Yes, I'm using AndEngine.